# How to increase pivot header height in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml

I currently creating apps in UWP (Universal Windows Platform). I was using pivot control and it seems I couldn't change the pivot item header height! It stays at 68 pixels. I have no idea which element should I modify to change it.

See this image for better explanation (click for full image): 
[image: unchanged pivot height]

Comment: Can you give sources from your pivot template ?

Comment: I found where you took your template : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i use same template than you.

So, to modify height i set Height on HeaderClipper (see screenshot below) on pivot style :

[image]

Hope this will help you.

---

**UPDATE:** Because pivot header height is static and can not be more than a small size, we have to set height manually after page is loaded

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PivotHeaderItem phItem in FindVisualChildren<PivotHeaderItem(mainPivot))
     {
         phItem.Height = 110;
    }
}

//Find all children
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c123ae3-2884-4d40-a5d1-0a22355fcd5f/uwpxamlhow-to-increase-pivot-header-height-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem but didn't want to use the code behind option.

Using the new Live Tree Debugger in Visual Studio I found that the height comes from the `PivotHeaderItem` default style.

If you add a copy of that style at an appropriate scope you can set the height using Xaml and you won't need any code.

I [blogged](http://blog.hompus.nl/2015/09/04/responsive-pivot-headers-in-universal-windows-platform-apps/) about this with a [sample](https://github.com/eNeRGy164/DynamicPivot) project.

Answer (score 3):

No need to copy the entire style for `PivotHeaderItem`, you can just override it directly in your Template for the Pivot.  Here is the relevant section you need to modify from the Sample project.

```
<!-- While used here to remove the spacing between header items, the PivotHeaderItem template can also be used to
display custom 'selected' visuals -->
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
</Style>
```